# css - background image not showing up

Tags: css

I feel retarted for even having to post something like this but for being a vet in css I have no idea why this time I can't get an image to show in the background of a div. Here is what I have

```
#leadarea {
background-image:(images/submarines-for-sale-at-seamagine.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:center;
height:360px;
width:1160px;
}

<div id="leadarea"></div>
```

I have triple checked my path to the image and its correct. In the same directory of the file I have an folder called "images" and the file to that image. If I type in the full url to that image in a browser I can see the image. Why is my div not showing that image?

Comment: maybe have `background-image:url(url-here.jpg)` i think you forgot about the `url` before the parenthesis, but I don't know if that's the issue so I'm just posting this as a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper syntax is:

```
background-image:url('images/submarines-for-sale-at-seamagine.jpg');
```

Also notice that the path is relative to the .css file placement.

Comment: OMG I cant believe I didnt see the "url" missing lol - answered

Answer (score 1):

Put the `url` in your `background-image`

```
background-image: url("your-image-path.jpg");
```

Try this to optimize your background definition in one line:

```
#leadarea {
    background: transparent url("http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-5PauJ-PHxns/UVjwME0X9YI/AAAAAAAAA4s/lsd9ZRsfCnE/s1600/coelho+escolha.jpg") no-repeat center;
    // background: color url("your-image-path.jpg") repeat position;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Check the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/R5cJp/2/